# Kineticsjs drawing arc with Kinetic.Shape

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas, kineticjs

Hi i want to build a loading animation, where a Doughnut Chart is becoming bigger and bigger. I need to do this with a custom shape, because i need the hole in the middle for other animations. What i get so far is:

> var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
>       container: 'loader',
>       width: 600,
>       height: 200 });
>
> var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
>
> var circle = new Kinetic.Circle({
>       x: stage.getWidth() / 2+200,
>       y: stage.getHeight() / 2,
>       radius: 70,
>       fill: 'red' });
>
> var x = stage.width / 2; var y = stage.height / 2; var radius = 75;
>   var startAngle = 1.1 * Math.PI; var endAngle = 1.9 * Math.PI; var
>   counterClockwise = false;
>
> var arc = new Kinetic.Shape({
>
> ```
> sceneFunc: function(context) {
>     context.beginPath();
>     context.arc(x, y, radius, startAngle, endAngle, counterClockwise);
>     context.closePath();
>     // KineticJS specific context method
>     context.fillStrokeShape(this);
> },
> fill: 'green',
> stroke: 'red',
> strokeWidth: 4 });
> ```
>
> // add the shape to the layer
>
> layer.add(arc);
>
> // add the layer to the stage stage.add(layer);

if some body could help me would be great

here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FabuBaracus/D9j3S/

Answer (score 0):

You can draw an adjustable arc using a Kinetic.Shape.

A Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/RZRVx/

First create an arc:

```
var arc = new Kinetic.Shape({
  sceneFunc: function(context) {
    context.beginPath();
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(this.cx,this.cy,this.radius,-PI2/4,PI2*this.arcPercent/100-PI2/4);
    // KineticJS specific context method
    context.fillStrokeShape(this);
  },
  stroke: 'green',
  strokeWidth:25
});
```

Then add some properties to that arc that define how big your arc will be:

```
arc.cx=100;
arc.cy=100;
arc.radius=75;
arc.arcPercent=33;  // percent is 0-100
```

And finally create a function that you can use to adjust the sweep of the arc

```
function setArcPercent(percent){
    arc.arcPercent=percent;
    layer.draw();
}
```